# Scrape image link from a streaming video

Tags: python-3.x, bash, web, web-scraping, scripting

I am trying to fetch the images in a timely fashion. Usually, I am doing so using ffmpeg toolkit. Unfortunately, ffmpeg is not working on blob format URLs as they are not the actual URLs. To fetch images from such websites (https://kingfisherfleet.com/live-cam/) I am copying the "poster = https://s7.ipcamlive.com/streams/070pgjxzximcozae3/snapshot.jpg" where the stream id = 070pgjxzximcozae3 keeps changing. So I have to manually update this path in the script.

I am looking for a way out to get this link image link directly which I can feed into my ffmpeg script.

My current approach is something like this:

```
sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers = {
    "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36",
    "referer":"https://g1.ipcamlive.com/",
    "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest",
}

metadata_url = "https://s7.ipcamlive.com/streams/"
r = sess.get(metadata_url, params={"NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD COME HERE, AND HOW TO GO FROM HERE TO GET THE LINK"})
```

Comment: @Cyrus I appreciate that, I just updated the code. This only place I am stuck is the params which should take changing string as well as the remaining part of the website.

Comment: Is https://www.ipcamlive.com/5d42fff5d1dab always the same URL?